# determine div position when page loading using either js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that has two parts, left is menu, right is content. And I want to implement a button to show or hide the menu(I've finished the animation). Here is the problem: when clicking a new page, browser can't remember whether the menu is hidden or not. By default, the menu is hidden.
My website http://alaneuler.com

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use local storage or cookie.

Comment: I've tried that, but the performance is wired. I don't know why.

Comment: whats the backend? most frameworks come with some sort of state/session management. otherwise localStorage

Comment: "I've tried that, but the performance is wired" what does that mean? also, if you've tried something that wasn't right you should add it to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LocalStorage with JS.

```
$(function() {
    if(typeof localStorage.getItem('showMenu') == "undefined")
        localStorage.setItem('showMenu', false);

    if(localStorage.getItem('showMenu'))
        $('#menu').show();

    $('#toggleButton').on('click', function() {
        if($('#menu').is(':visible')) {
            $('#menu').hide();
            localStorage.setItem('showMenu', false);
        } else {
            $('#menu').show();
            localStorage.setItem('showMenu', true);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks, I've finished!